# Drupal 6 catch form fails on validation in template file

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

How can I know in my template file: node-object.tpl.php that form falis on validation.

I want to use this because form is in hidden div and when I know that validation fails I can pre-open that div.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery on the client side to check  for validation and you can use a module to get server side validation done.

Jquery will be fast and user friendly and server side validation will make sure the submission is safe and no cross side scripting hacks are done.

Further research to get your work done:

1) Search for hook_form_validate() function in d7. This is a simple function which will do the validation for you.

2) Check out http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation for  client side validation.

If you still need more help then pls revert.

Comment: But I don't want to use client side validation, I always build forms with some variable $validate = FALSE and with that variable I can do anything. Client side validation in this moment isn't option form me. Thx for suggestion.

Comment: quote "I know that validation fails I can pre-open that div." how do you plan to pre-open the div after validation ?

Comment: If validation fails, I can get some parameter $validate = false; and than I can pass to my template file IF(!$validation){$div_class="block"} .